# Increment/decrement column when insert or update in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

So consider this:
I have two tables, first is "machines" and second "rentals". I have a boolean column in machines called "inRental" which is 0 when machine is not rented and 1 when it is. I also have boolean column in rentals called "finished" which is 0 when machine is still in rental and 1 when rental is finished (i don't delete rental entries because I want to track history of rentals). So what I want is, increment or set column 'machines.inRental' to 1 when a new rental entry for that machine is inserted in 'rentals'. For example when I create new rental I do:

```
INSERT INTO rentals VALUES (0,:machineID,0)
```

When this happens I want to:

```
UPDATE machines SET inRental=1 WHERE MachineID=:machineID
```

Similar I want when rental is finished:

```
UPDATE rentals SET finished=1 WHERE MachineID=:machineID
```

and

```
UPDATE machines SET inRental=0 WHERE MachineID=:machineID
```

Tables are like this:

```
RentalID  MachineID    finished   ...
.....................................
1         5            1                 
2         6            1                   
3         7            0                      


MachineID  inRental   ...
.........................
5          0                             
6          0                               
7          1
```

I guess this is achieved with trigger, but how? I also heard triggers are bad and it is better to avoid them. Is there a better way? I know that it maybe looks that column inRental is redundant and that I could just do JOINS, but I use a lot of times table 'machines' in subquery with other tables and I find it a little ineffective and messy to have to make JOINs in subqueries, or isn't it?

Comment: That's a strange design, to say the least. I would have a StartDate and EndDate columns in the rental table and when the current date doesn't fall inside the range the represent I know that the machine is not rented out.

Comment: I do have StartDate and EndDate, but when I enter new rental EndDate is just approximation since customer can have it for a longer period (we rent construction machines and rental periods are not fixed at begging). Anyway I could be incrementing EndDates or just leave it empty and know that it is in rental. But leaving empty kinda isn't an option since I WANT approximation of EndDate. This way application can remind me/warn me about a rental that is over approximated period. I complex things a bit, but thats how we need it.

Comment: Then have two end dates: one for the approximation, and another (set to year 3000) that serves to know if the machine is still in rental.

Comment: Well then just add another column for the actual endDate (call the first one Approximate or planned or whatever and the other one actual) - and only fill it with a value when the customer returns the machine - that way when it's null you know that the machine is not in stock to be rented out.

Comment: @trincot 3000 is too soon :-)

Comment: Well, I do wish Gregor a long life, but I wasn't thinking of such a span :-)

Comment: Thank you guys for answers (and long life wishes :) ). I consideres having two dates but its kinda like having that boolean 'finished' that I have or am I wrong? This way I guess you would suggest that I drop column 'inRental' in 'machines'? But this way when I want to SELECT through all my machines to see if they are out in rental or not JOINING tables would be inevitable and consider that after a year or two I have 100 or 200 machines/equipment, but in table rentals there are 10,000 entries. It would be inefficient to JOIN tables rather than have another column ('inRental') or am I wrong?

Comment: 1,000,000 records is small change for any self-respecting database now days.

Comment: Instead of two booleans, think about having one `state ENUM('available', 'rented', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Trigger usage is all depends upon your requirement, You can go for stored proc also. Refer : http://www.madeiradata.com/real-performance-impact-of-triggers/